# vite output css assetFileNames

Tags: vite

```
src
   |- MyComponent
      |
      |- index.js
      |- MyComponent.scss
```

src/MyComponent/index.js

```
import './MyComponent.scss';
export default SomeClass;
```

vite.config.js

```
{
  build: {
     rollupOptions : {
       input: {
         MyComponent: "./src/components/MyComponent"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

when build production. result folder.

```
dist
   |- MyComponent.js
   |- index.css. <-------- Can file name as MyComponent.css ?
```

If rollback vite2.0 and build, it's work.

```
dist
   |- MyComponent.js
   |- MyComponent.css.  <--- Correct
```

rollback Vite2.0, Vite3-beta13 is corrent